# How Sum values in dynamic table columns of qty

Tags: php, javascript, calculated-columns

How Sum values in dynamic table columns of qty, I can get the total of the price1, 
but I don't know to sum the column of qty, this is dynamic table, I can add row 
by the add button. Please help, I'm new on php.

`<html>
<head>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function tot(elem) {
var d=document.getElementById("total").value;
var total=Number(d); 
}
var total = 0;
function getValues() {
var qty1 = 0;
var unit = 0;
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
     if(obj[i].name == "qty1[]"){var qty1 = obj[i].value;}
     if(obj[i].name == "unit[]"){var unit = obj[i].value;}
     if(obj[i].name == "totala[]"){
     if(qty1 > 0 && unit > 0)
     {obj[i].value = (qty1*unit).toFixed(2);total+=(obj[i].value*1);}
                    else{obj[i].value = 0;total+=(obj[i].value*1);}
            }
         }
    document.getElementById("total").value = (total*1).toFixed(2);
    total=0;
}
</script>
<script>
function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
                function deleteRow(tableID)
{
        try
             {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
                    {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)
                        {
                        if (rowCount <= 1)
                            {
                            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                            break;
                            }
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(e)
                    {
                    alert(e);
                    }
   getValues();
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
 <table width="800" border="0">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5" align="center">Products</td>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
    <td><INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" /></td>
    <td>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <td width="169">qty</td>
    <td width="145">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="368">unit</td>
    <td width="151">price1</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
  <div>
<table width="800" border="0" class="box4_Box" id="dataTable">
<tr>
<td width="21" valign="top"><input name="chk[]" type="checkbox"/></td>

  <td width="280">
    <input type="text" name="qty1[]" id="qty" onkeyup="getValues()"onblur=""/></td>
  <td width="337"> 
    <input type="text" name="unit[]" id="unit" onkeyup="getValues()" onblur=""/></td>
  <td width="144">
    <input type="text" name="totala[]" id="totala" onkeyup="getValues()" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
    </div>
  <div>
  <table width="800" border="0">
  <tr>
     <td width="305"><input type="text" name="qtytotal" id="qtytotal" value="" /></td>
  <td width="337">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="144"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
  </div>
  </form>
 </body>
 </html>`

Comment: Ask question specifically to get specific tip. Don't want others to do programming on behalf of you. Why have you added full page with code. It is hard read full question to answer your question.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you need to make the `id` attributes unique when you copy the cells to the new row. Do you really need the inputs to have id's in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sumQty(tableID) {
    var total = 0;
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var colCount = row.cells.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < cellCount; j++) {
            var node = row.cells[j].childNodes[0];
            if (node.name == "qty[]") {
                total += parseInt(node.value);
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: From the input of qty[], do i need to put "onkeyup="sumQty('dataTable')" to get the result?? anything need on input of total??

Comment: My function doesn't display the sum anywhere, it just returns it. When to call it and what to do with the value is up to you.